# Is there a way to automatically call files to be used in a script?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that compares 2 XML files. Right now, I have the file locations hardcoded, but I need to find a way to have them be somehow called. Maybe using parameters would work? I've tried playing around but am not able to get anything to work. I know there's something about using a slash to somehow reference it? I'm really new to PS and am not really sure how to go about it.

Here's what I have:

```
[xml]$file1 = Get-Content "C:\Generic.xml"
[xml]$file2 = (Get-Content "C:\Comparison.xml")
 $file1
$file2
$file1.configuration
$Compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $file1.configuration.ChildNodes -DifferenceObject $file2.configuration.ChildNodes -IncludeEqual
    if ($compare.SideIndicator -eq "==") {
        "There is a match for all of the child nodes"
    }
    Else {
        "There is a child node missing"
    }

$file1.configuration.appSettings.add | more
$file2.configuration.appSettings.add | more
$Compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $file1.configuration.appSettings.add -DifferenceObject $file2.configuration.appSettings.add -Property key,value -IncludeEqual
foreach ($compare in $Compare) {
    if ($compare.SideIndicator -eq "==") {
        "There is a match for key $($compare.key) and value $($compare.value)"
    }
    if ($compare.SideIndicator -eq "<=") {
        "There is no match for key $($compare.key) and value $($compare.value)"
    }
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a function, this will allow you to execute the script with variable parameters of your choosing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6

So in your function you'd use most of the same code, but perhaps amend:

`[xml]$file1 = Get-Content "C:\Generic.xml"`

to

`[xml]$file1 = Get-Content $file1_path`

And then execute using a format such as:

`Compare-XML -file1_path "C:\Generic.xml"`